# Replace array keys (foreach loop) who matches another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've got poll results stored in a mysql database.
I try to output the results which go's well, but now I try to get the result in descending order (highest first) and with the right name. Now the output is like this:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r(array_count_values($array_a));
print "</pre>";

 //OUTPUTS first key is the poll option and second is how much it was voted for.
[4] => 1
[12] => 17
[2] => 3
[6] => 42
[8] => 6
[16] => 5
[3] => 30
[18] => 1
[1] => 5
```

First I like to replace the numbers with a name. This is where I got stuck. str_replace doesn't work cause it replaces all numbers matching but not the exact number. The foreach loops get it right but there a 17 numbers to be replaced so I like to use an array to get them from but don't know how.

```
foreach($array_a as &$value){
    if($value==1){
        $value = "opt1";
    }
}  

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '1';
$patterns[1] = '2';
$patterns[2] = '3';
$patterns[3] = '4';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'Car';
$replacements[1] = 'Boat';
$replacements[2] = 'Bike';
$replacements[3] = 'Photo';
```

The result I like to achieve:

```
 //OUTPUT
[Car] => 30
[Bike] => 25
[Paint] => 10
[Goat] => 5
[Photo] => 3
```

Comment: what result you want to achieve? show us the desired array.

Comment: i've add it to the original post

Comment: you could try using [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) function of php

Comment: asort works great for getting them into order ty

Comment: I use the arsort function to get it from high to low http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'Car';   // your key should be the key of $array_a here and 
$replacements[1] = 'Boat';  // value should be the key you want to be used
$replacements[5] = 'Bike';
$replacements[3] = 'Photo';


$finalPollArray = array();

foreach($replacements as $key => $value)
{
    $finalPollArray[$value] = $array_a[$key];
}  

$finalPollArray = asort($finalPollArray)

print "<pre>";
print_r($finalPollArray);
print "</pre>";
```

---

A very practical example would be:

```
$poll[5] = 13;
$poll[6] = 12;
$poll[3] = 10;
$poll[12] = 7;
$poll[8] = 6;
$poll[1] = 5;
$poll[7] = 5;
$poll[16] = 5;
$poll[13] = 4;

 // with this code I get the following output
$replacements = array();
$replacements[5] = 'Car';

$finalPollArrayA = array();

 foreach($replacements as $key => $value)
 {
     $finalPollArrayA[$value] = $poll[$key];
 }

 print "<pre>";
 print_r($finalPollArrayA);
 print "</pre>";
```

and this outputs me:

```
Array
(
    [Car] => 13
)
```

is it as expected?

Comment: I think 'opt'.($key+1), Rob needs 0=>1, 1=>2, etc.

Comment: thanks, i just missed the asort function, this should now output as expected!

Comment: this seem like a should work well, but I've forgot to point out that the 'opt' names are token names for things ask in the poll. I've updated the original post.

Comment: It seems it replaces by order but not by match (number -> thing) so now the names don't match the results...

Comment: You can make it replace with your own specific keys, not necessarily in an order, but just any numbers!, i have edit the post, so it doesnt makes you feel that things need to be in order!

Comment: ty. When I output the results(array_count_values) this is the top 3 [5] => 13 [6] => 12 [3] => 10. With the above code it changes with $replacements[5] = 'Car'; to output:  [Car] => 16 where key5 should output 13........... Key 16 outputs 5 [16] => 5 so maybe it should be used the other way around?

Comment: i didn't understand _[Car] => 13. But [16] => 5_

Comment: its works now! I use it after array_count_values. That makes the difference. Is it possible if the key isn't in the replacements array to keep the key and value anyway (I got some custom user input as well)